# Ошибка при создании отчёта Libre Office Access

Tags: sql, база-данных, libre-office

Всем доброго времени суток.

Libreoffice Access при попытке создать отчёт из SQL запроса выдаёт ошибку: Невозможно получить имена полей из «_public.courses_d»

Вот содержимое этого запроса:

```
SELECT cd.lector FROM public.courses_d cd;
```

Сперва грешил на то что он не распознаёт имя столбца. Пробовал так:

```
SELECT cd.lector as lector FROM public.courses_d cd;
```

И так:

```
SELECT cd.lector as "Лектор" FROM public.courses_d cd;
```

Всё равно выдаёт ошибку. Даже встроенный генератор запросов не может сгенерить такой, чтобы отчёт мог из него столбцы подхватить.

Гугление дало 0 результатов. Видимо проблема в серверной части. Но я не понимаю где искать.

Помогите плиз кто сталкивался.

Comment: А вы уверены, что название таблицы указано верно? Обратите внимание, что во втором абзаце `_public.courses_d` указано с нижним подчеркиванием

Comment: Пробовали `FROM public.courses_d AS cd`?

Comment: @cauf сам запрос выполняется. Я его тестировал в.т.ч. внутри Libre Office. Единственное на что он ругался, это когда я не включал этот режим:
[Картинка 1](https://hkar.ru/12tKr)

Comment: @Ainar-G попробовал. Результат нулевой. Заметил ещё что при неверном пароле пользователя выскакивает [ошибка со слетевшей кодировкой](https://hkar.ru/12tKz). Может в этом трабла?

Answer (score 1):

На всякий случай, если кому нужно решение. Создал представление:

```
CREATE VIEW test as SELECT cd.lector FROM public.courses_d cd;
```

И офис увидел поля. По запросу:

```
SELECT * FROM test;
```

Однако всё равно хотел бы знать в чём проблема. Не хочется на каждый чих создавать представления. Кроме того я не смогу создать форму на представлении из нескольких таблиц.

**UPD:**
У меня получилось создать форму по следующему запросу:

```
SELECT courses_d.* 
FROM "public".shooting_d shooting_d, "public".courses_d courses_d 
WHERE shooting_d.course_code = courses_d.course_code ;
```

То есть название схемы должно быть в кавычках. Думаю это как-то связано с тем что [тут](https://hkar.ru/12tKz) кракозябры и в итоге название схемы для него нечитаемо.
Было-бы хорошо узнать как это исправить, но, видимо, так тоже работать будет.

Видимо вопрос закрыт.

Comment: А, ну да, `public` - ключевое слово.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Извините не понял. public это ведь название схемы. Если я создам схему 'schema', то к таблицам из неё я буду в DBeaver обращаться как schema.*название таблицы*.
При этом офис вынуждает меня писать "schema".*название таблицы*. Я думаю тут что-то не так всё таки.

Comment: `public` - [ключевое](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/learn-about-access-reserved-words-and-symbols-ae9d9ada-3255-4b12-91a9-f855bdd9c5a2) [слово](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/reserved-words-access-custom-web-app). Поэтому, когда оно используется как название схемы, таблицы, колонки - его обязательно нужно брать в кавычки. Я так понимаю. Но с Access я дела почти не имел, могу ошибаться.